# Automatically update extracted Datasource on changing parameters from tableau server

Tags: tableau-api

I'm using some parameters in my `datasource`, but when I'm changing parameters, the `datasource` doesn't update.
how can I update `datasource` automatically with changing parameters?

Comment: Do you mean the parameters are used in custom SQL? Are you also using an extract?

Comment: @AlexBlakemore Yes, Yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using parameters in custom SQL and want the impact of the parameters reflected immediately, you need to use a live connection instead of an extract.